# nutch2.0 hadoop Input path does not exist

Tags: hadoop, hbase, nutch

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://yuqing-namenode:9000/user/yuqing/2
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:235)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:252)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:962)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:979)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$600(JobClient.java:174)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:897)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:850)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:850)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:500)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:530)
at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:50)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:219)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.runTool(Crawler.java:68)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.run(Crawler.java:136)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.run(Crawler.java:250)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.main(Crawler.java:257)
```

When I remove the config file of hadoop from nutch conf, the first line of error become:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/home/yuqing/workspace/nutch2.0/2
```

Once I run Nutch2.0 success with hbase, but now the full distribution is not work.
Hbase in full distribution runs normal, I can op it in shell.
next I create a folder in nutch2.0, then the crawler can running, but output of console seems unnormal.
Now I have to have a meal.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have input path. Excactly as hadoop said.
Check, that hdfs dfs -ls /user/yuqing/2 return something (2 should be file or directory)

As for the second part, when you remove hadoop configs, hadoop library uses internal configs (you can find them in distribution with names *-default.xml, f.e. core-default.xml), and hadoop functions in 'local' mode. In 'local' mode all paths are local (in local filesystem). 
So, when you reference file in 'hdfs' mode, f.e. hdfs dfs -ls /some/file, hadoop will lookup file in hdfs (hdfs://namenode.ip/some/file), but in local mode file will be searched in relative (typically file:/home/user/some/file). 
You can see that in your output: file:/home/yuqing/workspace/nutch2.0/2